# Removing deadlock on PostgreSQL layer by Cadcorp SIS?

Tags: postgresql, cadcorp-sis

I have just created a new table which I will want available for multiple connections at once. I have never had to consider this before as all tables in the past have been fine for this.

However this new tables seems to be creating a deadlock when two (or more) connections are attempted from Cadcorp SIS 9.

The first connection will open the table fine. The second will get stuck and throws back the following:

```
2019-04-29 09:57:22.610 BST [7276] ERROR:  deadlock detected
2019-04-29 09:57:22.610 BST [7276] DETAIL:  Process 7276 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 6798789 of database 774436; blocked by process 6168.
                Process 6168 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 6798789 of database 774436; blocked by process 7276.
                Process 7276: select ST_EstimatedExtent('public', 'mastermap', 'geometry') LIMIT 0
                Process 6168: DECLARE C8 NO SCROLL CURSOR FOR select ST_EstimatedExtent('public', 'mastermap', 'geometry')
2019-04-29 09:57:22.610 BST [7276] HINT:  See server log for query details.
2019-04-29 09:57:22.610 BST [7276] STATEMENT:  select ST_EstimatedExtent('public', 'mastermap', 'geometry') LIMIT 0
```

[image]

[image]

If I kill the blocking session, it actually allows the second one connection through without affecting the first one (so at this point both work fine). However if you then close one of the Cadcorp sessions and reopen, it just locks again.

How do I remove this type of lock permanently? It is not a dataset that anyone will ever edit, it's only for viewing/tracing purposes and i don't want to have to kill the session every time multiple connections open up.

I have read the docs on locking and unfortunately cannot make sense of them  (I am a SQL novice).

UPDATE AFTER RUNNING SUGGESTION FROM JGH:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.mastermap"
INFO:  index "mastermap_geometry_sidx" now contains 483426581 row versions in 3945914 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 8.43 s, system: 38.37 s, elapsed: 260.44 s.
INFO:  "mastermap": found 0 removable, 4 nonremovable row versions in 1 out of 22441174 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 59942
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 9.09 s, system: 38.46 s, elapsed: 261.42 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_776026"
INFO:  "pg_toast_776026": found 0 removable, 9 nonremovable row versions in 1 out of 205740 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 59943
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.01 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.22 s.
INFO:  analyzing "public.mastermap"
INFO:  "mastermap": scanned 30000 of 22441174 pages, containing 644561 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 482156852 estimated total rows
VACUUM

Query returned successfully in 8 min 50 secs.
```

Comment: could you add the desktop GIS you are using as client? as tag and in the body maybe? I suppose you can connect and read that same relation from multiple pgAdmin connections, so the actual client is important here.

Comment: Added it in (Cadcorp SIS 9)

Comment: Try running `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the table. (though the root of the issue might be far away from the displayed message)

Comment: @JGH please see the added code in my edit above for results of the query

Comment: Does it solve the problem?

Comment: Sadly not no. I'm on to Cadcorp support as well and they're saying they've never seen this before so unfortunately I'm a bit stuck

Comment: It might be down to Transaction Isolation in postgres https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/transaction-iso.html (not sure of your version of postgres)

Comment: @Mapperz I took a read of the docs. My config file shows the default Read Committed, so presumably this means it should be fine? I couldn't find anything about checking this is what it was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cadcorp have just informed me that the current release of SIS 9 doesn't actually support PostgreSQL 11 which will more than likely explain the issues.

I have been using SIS 9 with an older database successfully, so this certainly ties in with everything I have tested.

They have said PostgreSQL 11 is due to be tested with the next service release (9.1)

Comment: bingo the version makes a big difference, good to know.